# how to make a clause in hibernate mapping files?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to add a (where) condition in hibernate mapping file when fetching,
how could i do that for example `fetch="select" where id != 1` ,am not using annotations also, so please specify within the mapping (hbm) files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Hibernate documentation, you can specify a `where` clause when mapping a collection:

> #### [6.2. Collection mappings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-mapping)
>
> (...) The `<map>` element is
>   representative:
>
> ```
> <map
>     name="propertyName"                                         (1)
>     table="table_name"                                          (2)
>     schema="schema_name"                                        (3)
>     lazy="true|extra|false"                                     (4)
>     inverse="true|false"                                        (5)
>     cascade="all|none|save-update|delete|all-delete-orphan|delet(6)e-orphan"
>     sort="unsorted|natural|comparatorClass"                     (7)
>     order-by="column_name asc|desc"                             (8)
>     where="arbitrary sql where condition"                       (9)
>     fetch="join|select|subselect"                               (10)
>     batch-size="N"                                              (11)
>     access="field|property|ClassName"                           (12)
>     optimistic-lock="true|false"                                (13)
>     mutable="true|false"                                        (14)
>     node="element-name|."
>     embed-xml="true|false" 
> >
>
>     <key .... />
>     <map-key .... />
>     <element .... />
> </map>
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> (9) `where` (optional): specifies an
>   arbitrary SQL WHERE condition that is
>   used when retrieving or removing the
>   collection. This is useful if the
>   collection needs to contain only a
>   subset of the available data.

This is also supported at the [`<class>`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class) level.

Comment: Could you please give me a simple example using it, i tried to search for clear example but i can't find, am mapping a set and want to run clause WHERE ID != 1, regards

Comment: @Amr Well, what do you get when using `where="id != 1"`, what query gets generated?

Comment: ok all what i gonna say is you helped me for the second time in row, your answer is just perfect and it was my fault applying it, many thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps define a `<filter>` in the mapping file, and attach it to the class mapping definition.  See the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html_single/#objectstate-filters) for examples.

Comment: it needs a lot of configuration, and also to be enabled from code, is there another way to do that?